# How is this microphone and speaker piece called?

Tags: sound-card

I was trying to remove a broken jack (3.5mm) from my audio panel on the top of my case, which is a [Phanteks Eclipse P400](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/media/image/thumbnail/CA041PT_137309_750x750.jpg) and I disassembled it until I could extract the piece that you can see here:

[This goes to the motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McTrA.jpg)

[Side view of the same piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kkuj.jpg)

[Piece that pops from the top panel of the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uah8q.jpg)

[Same piece, side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmBgR.jpg)

Since I'd like to buy a replacement for this, I need to know how this is called, but I couldn't find anything during my searches, so you're my last chance. (I don't even  know if I selected the tag correctly...)

Comment: The first is an audio header, I think. I'm not sure you can find the whole assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ["5x2 pin header connector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_header) plus two ["3.5mm TRS jacks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) plus "a bunch of coloured wires". The individual parts are mostly standard (although *I think* you need to be careful about pin spacing and dimensions), but the whole assembly is likely just done for this specific product.